# Не хочет парсить даты из файла

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.*;


public class lab8_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("date.txt"));
        String line;
        List<LocalDateTime> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
            lines.add(LocalDateTime.parse(line, format));
        }
    }
}
```

Файл date.txt :

> 2003-01-06
>   2004-09-18
>   2011-10-13
>   2013-02-08
>   2015-11-01

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2003-01-06' could not be parsed at index 0
>       at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
>       at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
>       at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
>       at labs.lab8_Files.Text_Files.lab8_2.main(lab8_2.java:19)

Пытался менять формат, не помогло

Comment: "Пытался менять формат" - на пиво?

Comment: Файл был с BOM, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Дату без времени нужно парсить в LocalDate:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("date.txt"));
    String line;
    List<LocalDate> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        lines.add(LocalDate.parse(line, format));
    }
}
```

либо конвертировать в LocalDate в LocalDateTime:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("date.txt"));
    String line;
    List<LocalDateTime> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        lines.add(LocalDate.parse(line, format).atStartOfDay());
    }
}
```